# Slickgrid: scroll grid on range selection

Tags: scrollview, selection, slickgrid

Like in excel, I would like the grid automatically scrolls if the last selected cell is not into the visible part of the grid.
*onSelectedRangesChanged* event is fired at the end of the range selection process,  not during the selection process...
Thank for your help,
Mpe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107466/slickgrid-autoscroll-the-viewport-when-selecting-data

Comment: @BenMcIntyre Thks, I saw this post but I don't know where and how to use the provided code :( Maybe with a fiddle...